# Vuejs, why is this.$store.state.route.params.activityId undefined when I access it in store module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

I need to set the currentId in the store. I have it in the component, everything fine in the console:

```
async created() {
    const activityId = await this.$store.state.route.params.activityId
    activityId: 'activityId'
    console.log("here activityId: ", activityId)
    console.log('print all params: ', this.$store.state.route.params)
    console.log("STORE: ", this.$store.state)
  },
```

I've organised the store in modules, the one I'm working on is activity.js and it's working fine (I have all the activities saved in the store). I now need to set the current id and then set the single activity according to it (so I can access its data). 
Removing the non inherent code, what I have is:

```
import {
  activityId
} from '@/views/ActivityDetail'

const state = {
  currentActivityId: activityId
}

const mutations = {
  SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ID: (state, currentActivityId) => {
    state.currentActivityId = currentActivityId
  }
}

const actions = {
  setCurrentActivityId({
    commit
  }) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      commit('SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ID', '')
      resolve()
    })
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

In the module 'getters' I have, among the others (that are working fine):

```
activityId: state => state.activity.activityId,
```

Still `activityId: undefined`

I have `sync (store, router)` working, also `mode: 'history'` in the router, because before this I tried:

```
import {router} from '@/router'
const state = {
  currentActivityId: router.currentRoute.params.activityId,
}
```

I didn't do any change regarding the mode: history, so I don't know if the problem can be found here. But commenting it and making use of the currentRoute did not solve the problem.

The versions installed in my app are:
"vue-router": "3.0.6",
"vuex": "^3.1.0",
"vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"

Still `activityId: undefined`
Can anyone help, please?
Thank you

Comment: It is not clear how exactly your code is working. Which properties do you want to access and where are you accessing them? Please try to structure your question better.

Comment: As I know for storing data using Vuex you should use `this.$store.commit('relative path to exact mutation method', your data)`

Comment: `const activityId = ...` seems strange to have a const instead of a  `let` here ..

Comment: Your store looks like it has `state.currentActivityId`. So, `activityId: state => state.currentActivityId`?

Comment: @Wes Doyle yes you're right,  but it didn't solve the problem..

Comment: @DavidPi correct, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I read somewhere (can't find the link now) that probably what I am trying to do is just incorrect. The current activity id can't be saved in the store as it has local scope to the template it belongs. I am not sure about it.

Comment: @MarcRo Sorry if I haven't been clear enough. In the table there's a list of activities, on each row few properties of them and a button to open a page with more properties.I pass the id of the activity clicked as a parameter of the button. So I need the access the properties of the activity clicked. I haven't implemented this part yet, as I was focusing on getting the id of the current activity in the store, but now I am starting to think that's not the way. Please, if you can help... I know I am still not good in vue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I didn't actually use the currentActivityId to save the single activity. 
Here is what I did: 
in the template with all the activities, I modified the button like this:

```
<b-button
  v-b-tooltip.hover
  title="Mostra dettagli"
  variant="info"
  class="px-3"
  @click="goToDetailActivity((data.item), selectActivity(data.item))"
>
```

Now the button @click for the clicked activity triggers these two methods:

```
selectActivity(activity) {
      let currentActivity = activity;
      currentActivity = this.$store.getters.currentActivity;
      return currentActivity;
    },
    goToDetailActivity(activity) {
      console.log('OBJECT activity sent from all activities to detail: ', activity)
      const activityData = {
        activity: activity
      }
      console.log('ACTIVITY DATA IN ALL: ', activityData)
      this.loading = true
      this.$store.dispatch('activity/setCurrentActivity', activityData).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'DettaglioAttivita',
          params: {
            activityId: activity.id
          }
        })
        this.loading = false
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('ERROR IN fetching activityData: ', err)
        this.loading = false
      })
    }
```

In the getters module:

```
currentActivity: state => state.activity.currentActivity
```

In store/activity.js:
-state:

```
currentActivity: ''
```

-mutations:

```
SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY: (state, activityData) => {
    state.currentActivity = activityData
  }
```

-actions:

```
setCurrentActivity({ commit }, activityData) {
    commit('SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY', activityData)
  }
```

I needed the payolad (activityData) to pass the data. And obviously rethink the entire thing.
Now it works. 
If I refresh the page, though, I loose all the data. I'm dealing with it with the vuex-persitedstate plugin. But this is another story. 
Thank you to anyone who took the time to have a look at it.

Comment: Just to let you know, vuex-persitedstate plugin works.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are trying to do is to `set` the ID of a specific 'activity' in your store so you can use this ID to show more information about this 'activity' on a different page.

To set data in your store you should absolutely always use a `commit()`, even better if you use an `action()` that triggers the `commit()`. Do not set the `state` of your `store` directly (e.g. `this.$store.state.bar = 23` <- don't do that).

Here is an example of how you could design the functionality:

```
// Template in 'activitySelecotr.vue'
...
<div
  v-for="activity in activities"
  :key="activity.id"
  class="activity"
>
  // other stuff
  <button @click="showMoreInfo(activity.id)">Show more Information</button>
</div>
...

computed: {
  activities() {
    return this.$store.state.allActivities;
  },
  ...
}

methods: {
  showMoreInfo(activityId) {
    this.$store.dispatch('activityModule/setCurrentActivityId', activityId);
  },
  ...
}
```

---

```
// in 'activityDetails.vue'
...
computed: {
  activityId() {
    return this.$store.state.activityModule.currentActivityId;
  },
  ...
},
created() {
  console.log("activityId: ", this.activityId);
},
...
```

---

```
// store/activityModule.js

const state = {
  ...
  currentActivityId: null,
};

const actions = {
  setCurrentActivityId({ commit }, activityId) {
    // do stuff, for example load activity data
    commit('SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ID', activityId);
  },
  ...
};

const mutations = {
  SET_CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ID(state, activityId) {
    state.currentActivityId = activityId;
  },
  ...
};
```

Why your code is not working is hard to answer with the information you provide. But I can tell you that at least the code in your `created()` function is not valid JavaScript.

```
async created() {
  // const activityId = await this.$store.state.route.params.activityId
  // ^ why is your route stored in your store? You can do the following:
  const activityId = this.$route.params.activityId;

  activityId: 'activityId' // 'activityId' is is a const and cannot be reassigned. Also you need to reasign with '='; ':' is invalid JavaScript.
  console.log("here activityId: ", activityId)
  console.log('print all params: ', this.$store.state.route.params)
  console.log("STORE: ", this.$store.state)
},
```

Comment: Thank you @MarcRo, thanks for suggesting me these tips, I updated the code accordingly. Unfortunately now the console says , in red, ```activityId is read-only```, I don't exactly know what it means...

Comment: You are most likely trying to re-assign `activityId`. You cannot do that within my code example because `activityId` is a `const`. If you want to change its value after declaration it needs to be a `let`.  I recommend you read up about these!

Comment: I will! Thanks a lot again.

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/update-store-variable-value-on-click-between-templates/18426/10 I found this post, even if old it's similar to what I need. And I've update my code too (the last answer is mine), just trying to get and save the single activity object to the store without using the activityId (I use it only for the dynamic routing). I think I am a bit closer, but still not working... @MarcRo Please have a look, thanks!

Comment: The code in your last answer (the updated version in the end) is correct and should work.

Comment: Yes it does :) But happiness doesn't last long... Refreshing the page I loose all the data again, so I'm dealing with it using  vuex-persitedstate plugin. Hope it won't take me long... Thank you @MarcRo